# How to update CORS rules for existing blob images in Azure?

Tags: azure, xmlhttprequest, blob, azure-blob-storage

I want to apply `Access-Control-Allow-Origin as *` for all my existing blob images.
I have added CORS settings to the azure.
But it is applying to new added images only.

How can `Access-Control-Allow-Origin as *`can be applied to existing images as well?

Do I need to replace all images or can I edit them?

Comment: CORS settings are applied at the account level and is applicable to all blobs. Please edit your question and include more details like the error you're getting when accessing older data.

Comment: @GauravMantri 'Owner' is my role in azure ,there are lots of blob images are added while ago,just now i have added CORS roles to my service,but it is not appling to all exsisting images,it is applying to new images only.

Comment: i'm getting "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested " error with priviously added images.

Comment: @Himang - please *edit your question* - details like error messages should not be placed in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS settings for blob storage are always applied for the whole account. This means it also applies to existing files. If you have trouble with your CORS requests for "old" files, the most common reason is that your browser cached the CORS response it did previously. Try changing the CORS settings and accessing the file in a private tab, clear your caches or try a different browser/machine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services

Comment: you are absolutely right!It was a cache issue.Thank you!

Comment: you can also pass a version number with your url to update caches of all images like:https://xyj/images/image.png?v=1